# Visual Studio 2015 include paths

Tags: visual-studio-2015, include, project, include-path

I seem to fail to understand how VS 2015 handles include paths. I have put the folders I need VS to scan for included files in the following places in the "Properties" pane of my project :

Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories

Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

But when I ask for a build I get :

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory
```

The spelling has been double-checked. I tried it with a dummy project which I can send, same behavior. I have tried with both slash and anti-slash. Actually some folders are subfolders of the project folders and do not require any slash or anti-slash in their path description (simply the folder name). Those also fail to be scanned and their contents remains unfound by the compiler.

I also tried specifying the path manually in the include directive, this works.

I also opened a project where everything is working and I added a new include directive to a newly created file in a folder which I added to the include path. This project now fails to compile.

Better yet, still using that old project that was compiling fine, if I remove one (or even all) folders from the Additional Include Directories filed in C/C++ > General **it still compiles !** So this must be the wrong place to specify include dirs !

What do I not know here ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please check if you, didn't misspell one of the involved paths/filenames

Comment: The spelling is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

In Visual Studio you can have multiple configurations (e.g. Debug or Release) and target platform (e.g. x86 or x64).

All properties (like include paths) also have a variant for each combination of configuration and platform.

When editing properties you only edit those properties for the combination of configuration and platform you set at the top.

That means I was editing the include paths for one configuration/platform combination and compiling for another.

This is terrible design, but alright. At least there is a possibility to specify that you want to edit properties for all configurations and all platforms (last option in the respective drop-down menu for configurations and for platforms).

Answer (score -1):

I usually start by putting the entire path in the include when including a new file.  Once that compile I move the directory into the location I want it in (usually Additional Include Directories) and finally once that work use env var when applicable.

There is also "" vs <> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I happen to have ready-made sources and  cannot manually change all include directives as they are too numerous. Consider I am on step 2 or your process. Moreover, I am aware of "" vs <> and know I need to use "".